# How do I remove my Windows Live information from Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I had to open an IRM protected PowerPoint file so the first time I logged in it asked me for the username and password. I was given permission to one specific email ID so I used it to login. But now, I am no longer using that PC. I don't want my info to be saved on the office application anymore. Please help & Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Obtain that computer, and ensure you are [signed out](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/sign-out-microsoft-office-2013/) of that instance of Office.

[image]

I would suspect that alone will be enough to protect your identity, but maybe run some clean up of temporary files and caches (perhaps use a tool such as [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)) -- just for peace of mind, and because it won't take very long to do. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but when I checked the Account section, I don't see any user information. I just see the option to Sign in and there is no User information. Please help!! Thanks.

Comment: If you see a "Sign In" link then you're not signed in.  So there's no problem?